# Mongo aggregation pipeline : How can I access one group stage variable in subsequent stage?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two collections here :

```
> db.Unit.find({}).limit(1).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b6878de1648d05903e1beb"),
    "number" : "07in15in4",
    "owner" : {
            "name" : "vacant"
    },
    "floor" : 15,
    "tower" : 4,
    "VisitorLogs" : [
            ObjectId("58b6878ee1648d05903e1d22"),
            ObjectId("58b6878ee1648d05903e236e"),
            ObjectId("58b6878ee1648d05903e23c9"),
            ObjectId("58b6878ee1648d05903e2454"),
            ObjectId("58b6878ee1648d05903e2915"),
            ObjectId("58b6878ee1648d05903e2aae"),
            ObjectId("58b6878ee1648d05903e2b93")
    ]
```

}

and

```
> db.VisitorLog.find({}).limit(1).pretty()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58b6878fe1648d05903e2efa"), "purpose" : "WorkHere" }
```

VisitorLogs in the Unit collection refers to the second collection, i.e. VisitorLog.

I need to find the the units which have the maximum number of visits for each purpose.

I tried this  in *mongo shell*:

```
units=db.Unit
units.aggregate([
    {$match:{'VisitorLogs':{$gt:[]}}},
    {$unwind:'$VisitorLogs'},
    {$lookup:{
        from:"VisitorLog", 
        localField:"VisitorLogs", 
        foreignField:"_id", 
        as:"log"}
      },
    {$group:{_id:{number:"$number", purpose:"$log.purpose"}, count:{$sum:1}}},
    {$sort:{count:-1}},
    {$group:{_id:"$_id.purpose", unit:{$first:"$_id.number"}}},
    {$limit:10}
])
```

I get the following result :

```
{ "_id" : [ "Business" ], "unit" : "05in12in2" }
{ "_id" : [ "WorkHere" ], "unit" : "09in04in2" }
{ "_id" : [ "Casual" ], "unit" : "10in05in2" }
{ "_id" : [ "JobInterview" ], "unit" : "05in14in2" }
```

This means that, for example, unit number 05in12in2 had the maximum visits which had the purpose "Business"

I now want to get the **number** of "business" visits that 05in12in2 had. 
I think its in "count" variable of the first group stage.

How do I access that ? I tried `{$group:{_id:"$_id.purpose", unit:{$first:"$_id.number"}, visits:"$count"}},` in the second last stage, i.e just before the *limit stage* but I get error :

```
> units.aggregate([
... {$match:{'VisitorLogs':{$gt:[]}}},
... {$unwind:'$VisitorLogs'},
... {$lookup:{from:"VisitorLog", localField:"VisitorLogs", foreignField:"_id", as:"log"}},
... {$group:{_id:{number:"$number", purpose:"$log.purpose"}, count:{$sum:1}}},
... {$sort:{count:-1}},
... {$group:{_id:"$_id.purpose", unit:{$first:"$_id.number"}, visits:"$count"}},
... {$limit:10}
... ])
assert: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "the group aggregate field 'visits' must be defined as an expression inside an object",
    "code" : 15951
} : aggregate failed
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:13:14
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:287:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1312:5
@(shell):1:1
```

Can someone please help me ?

Comment: I'm not sure about the logic, but to access count variable you have to use the variable with expression. Something like `{$group:{_id:"$_id.purpose", unit:{$first:"$_id.number"}, visits:{$first:"$count"}}}` or to sum you can try `{$group:{_id:"$_id.purpose", unit:{$first:"$_id.number"}, visits:{$sum:"$count"}}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following outputs what I needed :

```
units.aggregate([
    {$match:{'VisitorLogs':{$gt:[]}}},
    {$unwind:'$VisitorLogs'},
    {$lookup:{from:"VisitorLog", localField:"VisitorLogs", foreignField:"_id", as:"log"}},
    {$group:{_id:{number:"$number", purpose:"$log.purpose"}, count:{$sum:1}}},
    {$sort:{count:-1}},
    {$group:{_id:"$_id.purpose", number:{$first:"$_id.number"}, visits:{$first:"$count"}}},
    {$limit:10}
               ])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this information, but you are cutting it off by the `$group` stage. Just change the stage to the following (notice the last argument):

```
{ $group : {
  _id : "$_id.purpose",
  unit : { $first : "$_id.number" },
  visits : { $first : "$count" }
}}
```